# Can't play multiple youtube live at same time with react native(iOS)

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, youtubeplayer

I am developing an ios app that allows users to watch multiple youtube streams at the same time. I am using react-native as the framework.

It works without any problem on the simulator. However, when I test the app on my real device, it just can't play the stream at the same time. While a stream is playing, if I play another stream, the previous stream stop.

I tried using [react-native-youtube-iframe](https://github.com/LonelyCpp/react-native-youtube-iframe) and [react-native-youtube](https://github.com/davidohayon669/react-native-youtube) to play the stream.
I also tried `expo eject` to eject the project but it doesn't solve the problem.

I am using iOS 14.4 on both simulator and real device. The version of react-native is 0.63.4.

Is there any way to play multiple stream at same time?